# Button to delete row from table - PHP SQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a web page that outputs data from my sql database. Each row has a delete button that should delete the data in this particular row. I am having a issue where when I click the delete button it always deletes the row with the first/lowest ID regardless of which button I click. It doesnt delete the row I want it to delete. Here is my code:
HTML

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">
<?php
$sql = "
    SELECT *
      FROM playerTeam
";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
?>      
<table>
    <?php
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
         while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']?>"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="fName[]" value="<?php echo $row['firstName']?>"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="sName[]" value="<?php echo $row['surName']?>"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="team[]" value="<?php echo $row['team']?>"></td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete"></td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="update" value="Update"></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        }
    } 
    ?>
    </table>
</form>
```

process.php

```
if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $sql = "DELETE FROM playerTeam WHERE id='$id'";

    if (mysqli_query($connection, $sql)) {
        echo "Record deleted";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($connection);
    }
}
```

please could someone help me. Thanks

Comment: `input type="submit"` doesn't have a name, so your `name=delete` gets ignored

Comment: Try echoing out `$id` to double check if it is the row you want to delete

Comment: @luweiqi when I echo `$id` it doesnt output the right value, every button always outputs the first id in my table. If I make the hidden id input into a array and itterate over it, it outputs all of the id's.

Answer (score 1):

Because you delete the value of last id in

```
$id = $_POST['id'];

$sql = "DELETE FROM playerTeam WHERE id='$id'";
```

the value of `$_POST['id']` is equal to last row in `<?php echo $row['id']?>`
in each run of the while the `$_POST['id']` value replaced by new `$row['id']` so the last on would be read in  `$_POST['id']`

Answer (score 1):

As you are using `while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))`, this will loop to the last row in your MySQL Table, thus every time, it will have the last `id` of your table.

You can code it in a way that your delete script will get the `id`. So, your delete button for each row will be have the `row id`, e.g. `process.php?1`, `process.php?2`, `process.php?3` and so on.

`tablepage.php` *(not sure of your page's real name)*

Replace this line:

```
<td><input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete"></td>
```

With this:

```
<td><p><a href="/process.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>"></td>
```

`process.php?id=1`

```
// this will get `id=1` and thus your `id` will be `1`, and it will delete row `1`.
$id = $_GET['id'];

$sql = "DELETE FROM playerTeam WHERE id='$id'";

if (mysqli_query($connection, $sql)) {
    echo "Record deleted";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($connection);
}
```

Hope that helps, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, if i use e.g `$sql = "SELECT * FROM playerTeam WHERE id=1"` wont this just output the one row that contains the id value of 1

Comment: @SnowmanPusha Yes, but isn't that you want to delete one row?

Comment: yes I want to delete one row, but I want the user to choose the row by clicking the delete button. Each row has a delete button which when clicked deletes that particular row. Apologies if my op wasnt clear.

Comment: @SnowmanPusha Updated code, maybe it's a better solution, thanks

Answer (score 0):

In actual in this condition ,use ajax and jquery is much more easier i think .But do only by `php` gonna be use logic code

```
  $i = 0;
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
     {
     ?>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="id_<?= $i ?>" value="<?php echo $row['id']?>"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="fName[]" value="<?php echo $row['firstName']?>"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="sName[]" value="<?php echo $row['surName']?>"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="team[]" value="<?php echo $row['team']?>"></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="delete[<?= $i ?>]" value="Delete"></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="update[<?= $i ?>]" value="Update"></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
      $i++; //for unique num for each row
    }
```

process.php

```
if (isset($_POST['delete'])){
    $delete_id = array_keys($_POST['delete']);//print array key as a array
    $delete_id = $delete_id[0];//so get array key
    $id = $_POST["id_$delete_id"];//get its relative id
    .....
 }
```